# update multiples fields with sql alchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
    user = { "email" : "my_new_email@example.com", "age" : 20, "city" : "London", "country" : "UK", "language" : "English", "profession" : "developer", "employeer" : "BBC" }

    admin = User.query.filter_by(username='admin').first()

    admin.email = user["email"]
    admin.age = user["age"]
    admin.city = user["city"]
    admin.country = user["country"]
    admin.language = user["language"]
    admin.profession = user["profession"]
    admin.employeer = user["employeer"]
    ....
    ....
    db.session.commit()
```

There is any way to avoid this implicit update? What I mean is, this works fine if the update is only one or two fields, but a massive update with a large set of data is not practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just supply that dictionary to the update clause:

```
data = { "email" : "my_new_email@example.com", "age" : 20, "city" : "London", "country" : "UK", "language" : "English", "profession" : "developer", "employeer" : "BBC" }
User.query.filter_by(username='admin').update(data)
db.session.commit()
```